# How to remove unwanted candidates from helm-semantic-or-imenu?

Tags: helm, semantic-mode, imenu, helm-sources

Helm has inbuilt function `helm-semantic-or-imenu`. When this function is called, it shows all candidates including `variables`, `dependencies` e.t.c.

I mostly use it only for `functions` and `classes`. I want to remove all other candidates and include only `functions` & `classes` in it.

I checked source code of `helm-semantic-or-imenu` to modify `helm sources` but that looks quite complicated for me. Any help on removing selected candidates from source is appreciated.